# How Configure / Debug Openerp/Odoo In eclipse '' WINDOWS "

Tags: eclipse, windows, odoo, pydev

Welcome
I searched the Internet for how to debug Odoo in Eclipse for  Windows, 
I did not find the way only to Unix/linux server 
Does anyone know the step of configurate this 
thinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to debug Odoo in Eclipse under Windows?
 here is a complete guide to Odoo development under Windows 7 (although it is very similiar under Windows 8, so you should be fine using this guide under that operating system). What will you need:

```
A machine with Windows 7 installed on it
Internet connection
An hour of time to prepare your environment
```

NOTE - This is a guide for Odoo v7 development under Windows, therefore it might, but not necessarily will work for v8 - there might be some dependencies problems.

See this link>>

```
 https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/how-to/developers-13/how-to-debug-odoo-in-eclipse-under-winows-36105
```

[Debug Openerp/Odoo In eclipse](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-debug-odoo-in-eclipse-under-winows-36105)